# how to change dataframe column in pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe df1 with columns as partnumber and car.

EXAMPLE:

```
partnumber    car
P1            1
 P2           2
  P3          1
P4            2
```

partnumber column needs to be stripped to remove whitespaces, if i run
df1['partnumber'] = df1['partnumber'].map(lambda x:str(x).strip())

this changes the sequence of partnumber, please could you advise.

Comment: `df1['partnumber'] = df1['partnumber'].astype(str).str.strip()`

Comment: `this changes the sequence of partnumber` - can you explain?

Comment: When stating whats happening its better to also show us the evidence.